# transform.SetAsLastSibling(); lag / glitching in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hierarchy

https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/e0able/i_need_help_more_info_in_comments/

im using transform.SetAsLastSibling(); and it works well one time and the other its glitches and clips with the other siblings.

watch the video. it has the code at the end and more details!

Comment: I honestly can't see the issue in your video.

Comment: @Draco18s I think he means that on the left the arrow "blinks" once when the right panel should overlap it

Comment: YES that's what I meant. sorry, I was so unclear. yes, it's overlapping when it shouldn't. and causing it to glitch like that. You can clearly see in the Hierarchy that they are at the correct index but still glitch.